# How to create a linked service for azure key vault in ADF version2?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-keyvault

I've to create a pipeline which will copy data from one blob to another blob & I would like to use azure data factory version 2 with key vault. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

You need a `Azure Key Vault` linked service to be created first -

```
{
    "name": "AzureKeyVaultLinkedService",
    "properties": {
    "type": "AzureKeyVault",
    "typeProperties": {
        "baseUrl": "https://<azureKeyVaultName>.vault.azure.net"
        }
    }
}
```

Then when you are creating your `Azure Blob Storage` linkedservice just refer the `Azure Key Vault` property for your `connectiongString` or `sasUri` to reference the secret stored in your key vault -

```
{
    "name": "AzureStorageLinkedService",
    "properties": {
        "type": "AzureStorage",
        "typeProperties": {
            "connectionString": {
                "type": "AzureKeyVaultSecret",
                "secretName": "<secret name in AKV>",
                "store":{
                    "referenceName": "<Azure Key Vault linked service>",
                    "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
                }
            }
        },
        "connectVia": {
            "referenceName": "<name of Integration Runtime>",
            "type": "IntegrationRuntimeReference"
        }
    }
}
```

Detailed information to be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/store-credentials-in-key-vault).

Comment: What is the format of `<Azure Key Vault linked service>` supposed to be?  And what is `<name of Integration Runtime>`?

Comment: Looks like your link to more information requires authentication.

Comment: @jschmitter - 
1. `<Azure Key Vault linked service>` should be name of the linked service that you would create first. 
2. `<name of Integration Runtime>` should be the name you have chosen your integration runtime to be
3. updated the url

Comment: I've done some testing and it looks like the "connectVia" block is optional.